# Dual Convex Problem for a Problem including Total Variation

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-optimization

For a convex problem including total variation, like 
$$
(1) \qquad  \underset {\widehat{x}} {\text{minimize}}  \hspace{0.3cm} \Vert \widehat{x} \Vert_{TV}  \\
\qquad s.t. \hspace{0.3cm} y = F_n \widehat{x} 
$$
where $x$ is continuous-time signal which is a weighted superposition of spikes:
$$
(2) \qquad x = \sum_j a_j \delta_{t_j} 
$$
and the minimization is carried out over the set of all finite complex measures x supported on [0,1] and $F_n$ is the linear map collecting the lowest $n=2f_c+1 $ frequency coefficients. In fact the constraint of the above problem is a matrix notation to relate the data $y$ and the object $x$ in the following equation:
$$
(3) \qquad y(k) = \int_0^1 e^{-i2\pi kt}x dt = \sum_ja_je^{-i2\pi kt_j} \hspace{0.3cm} ,\hspace{1cm}  k \in \mathbb{Z},|k|\leq f_c .
$$ 
In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5871), the convex problem dual to (1) is introduced as
$$
(4) \qquad \underset {c}{\text{maximize}} \hspace{0.2cm} Re \langle y,c \rangle \\
 \qquad s.t. \qquad \Vert F_n^{^{*}}c \Vert \leq 1 ;
$$
the constraint imposes that the modulus of the trigonometric polynomial
$$
F_n^{^{*}}c(t) = \sum_{|k| \leq f_c }c_ke^{i2\pi kt}
$$
be uniformly bounded by 1 over the interval [0,1].
And Finally, the form of the dual problem is:
$$
(5) \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \underset {c}{\text{maximize}} \hspace{0.2cm} Re \langle y,c \rangle \\
\qquad \qquad s.t. \hspace{0.2cm}
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      Q & c\\
      c^* & 1
    \end{array} 
\right] \succeq 0 , \quad \sum_{i=1}^{n-j}Q_{i,i+j}= 
\begin{cases}
1,  & j=0 \\[2ex]
0, & j=1,...,n-1
\end{cases}
$$
What's going on here? How the equation (4) is obtained from (1)?

Comment: You should consult the PhD thesis of the second author Carlos Fernandez-Granda, where this is explained in detail. If you want to know more about the bounded real lemma, which explains why (4) can be recast as the semidefinite program (5), you might want to consult the book Positive Trigonometric Polynomials and Signal Processing Applications by Prof. Bogdan Dumitrescu.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0562.pdf) especially section 3.1, where they explain this kind of reasoning.

There are a lot more explanations spread out through the literature. For example [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7094450) as well.